# ¿Cómo enviar datos mediante un formulario usando PHP?

Tags: php, html, formularios

¿Es posible enviar datos mediante un formulario `HTML` y posterior procesarla mediante `PHP`?

Me gustaría usar solo `PHP`, sé que en `AJAX` si es posible.

En caso que fuera posible mediante `PHP`, como puedo obtener los valores de mis inputs usando el método `POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente usando la *superglobal* `$_POST` podrías obtener tus datos.

**$_POST:**

Un array asociativo de variables pasadas al script actual a través del método POST de HTTP cuando se emplea application/x-www-form-urlencoded o multipart/form-data como Content-Type de HTTP en la petición.

> **Nota:**
>       Esta es una 'superglobal' o una variable automatic global. Significa simplemente que es una variable que está disponible en cualquier parte del script. No hace falta hacer global $variable; para acceder a la misma desde funciones o métodos.

[manual $_POST](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php)

Un simple ejemplo de orientación:

*HTML*

```
<form method="POST" action="procesar.php">
   <input type="text" name="nombre" />
   <input type="text" name="apellidos" />
   <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

*procesar.php*

```
//Reseteo
$nombre = $apellidos = NULL;

//Si esta defenido nuestro formulario
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

   //Obtenemos datos mediante la 'superglobal' $_POST pasando el nombre del identificador 'name' del formulario.
   $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
   $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];

   //Hacemos algo.
   //Imprimos datos.
   echo $nombre . " " . $apellidos;

    //Muestra información sobre una variable.
   //var_dump($_POST); 
}
```

Aquí podrás encontrar un ejemplo más completo:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

Answer (score 1):

Aunque no le encuentro sentido a tu pregunta, de que se puede se puede, puedes mandar toda la información como un JSON String suponiendo que sean los parámetros a enviar:

```
data : {
    formularioUnaVar: JSON.stringify({
        'param_a': 23,
        'param_b': 'hola',
        ...
        'param_n': ''
    })
}
```

incluso la podrías meter en un get teniendo cierto cuidado con los caracteres especiales:

```
let formularioUnaVar: JSON.stringify({
    'param_a': 23,
    'param_b': 'hola',
    ...
    'param_n': ''
});

url = "http://algun.dominio.com/" + encodeURI(formularioUnaVar);
```

En el servidor deberias hacer el camino inverso desenpaquetando, pero bueno se puede, ahora es una buena practica, y la respuesta rotunda es NO.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder, se que no tiene sentido mi pregunta ya que ni yo mismo se porque pregunte algo que ya sabia XD, creo que me confundi por unos minutos y pregunte.... Debo de dormir un poco más....

Comment: Igual por lo visto re formulaste la pregunta, por lo que mi respuesta quedo sin sentido